# TornadoFX/JavaFX treeview doesnt repopulate correctly after mutating multiple ObservableList

Tags: javafx, treeview, populate, tornadofx, observablelist

### Problem description

I have a treeview (TornadoFX) which gets populated with 3 Observable Lists. If I mutate the 3 lists (first clear them than add new content) **the treeview only contains the content of one of the Observable Lists**.

### The interpretation of my debugging

The treewiev actualises itself in the moment the first List haves its new content and the other 2 are still empty. It does not actualise itself as soon as the other 2 Lists gain their new content.

### What I have tried so far

- calling treeview.root.children.clear() before I mutate the List to empty the treewiev (same outcome)
- calling treeview.refresh() after all Lists have been set (same outcome)

### My (more or less pseudo) Code

```
{//Classes
 R extends X
 A(val name :String) extends X
 B(val name :String, val A :String) extends X
 C(val B :String) extends X
}

{//this is how the Lists get their content each time
 private val aList = observableListOf<A>()
 private val bList = observableListOf<B>()
 private val cList = observableListOf<C>()

 fun setLists(){
     a.clear()
     b.clear()
     c.clear()
     //...
     a.add(...)
     b.add(...)
     c.add(...)

 }
}

{
 treeview<X> {
 root = TreeItem(R)
            populate{ parent ->
                if (parent == root){
                    aList
                } else if (parent.value is A){
                    bList.filter { it.A == parent.value.name } //works always
                }else if (parent.value is B){
                    cList.filter { it.B == parent.value.name } //works at first start but not after set setLists() get recalled
                }else {
                    emptyList<X>() //not sure if this is really needed but the compiler needs something here
                }
            }
 }
}
```

### Side Question

Ignore this Question if you want: Intelij is able to run my TornadoFX application (from main or from App with the TornadoFX Plugin), but if I try to export it it doesnt run (neither the jar nor the jnlp). Even if I select TornadoFX and all the other Libraries in the Artifact menu. BUT: if I select Native Bundle -> image in the JavaFX tab, the resulting exe (and only the exe) is working. I also tried to create a shadowJar with com.github.johnrengelman.shadow 5.2.0 Plugin but that also didnt work. So how can I export the Program as a jar (a fatjar including TornadoFX in best case)?

Comment: @fabian Sry thats a typo that happen as I abstracted away the actual classnames with a simple text editor. I will correct it.
Its correct in the actual code, and as I said the treeview gets populated correctly the first time, I only get problems if I mutate the list again afterwards.

Edit: I corrected the typo

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't know if it's the perfect solution but I simply clear the children and populate the treeview again. It works, but if that is the intended way it's not as "reactive" as I thought it is.